# Is is mandatory to convert status from PIO (Person of Indian Origin) to OCI (Overseas Citizen of India)?

Tags: indian-citizens

I am working in USA on H1B VISA. My son was born in USA. He is 2 years old now. He currently has PIO card. When he visited India last time, He got "LIFE TIME" stamp on PIO.

In this situation is it mandatory to convert his PIO card to OCI?

Comment: http://www.cgisf.org/page/display/30/231